# Raspberry pi 4 very unreliable access point

Tags: access-point, raspberry-pi-os-buster

I have followed a guide:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md
To create an access point for my system. I have sucesfully created an access point and I can see it on the network list on my mobile phone.

However, I notice that this network have various issues. For example, when connecting to this network on my phone, sometimes I am getting "wrong password" error. However, trying multiple times with the same password will eventually connect.

I mainly use this access point to connect to my remote ESP32 devices and sometimes my devices would not connect to this wifi!. It would literally take 10's of times restarting my device untill it finally connected succesfully to this network.

Did anyone else had any or simmilar probles with this access point on raspberry device?

On my esp32 devices , i just use simple function:

```
const char* ssid = "NameOfNetwork";
const char* password = "password123";

void setup_wifi() {
  delay(10);
  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  //WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {

    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
```

And sometimes it never conencts:
[image]

Comment: If you think you may have done something wrong, we can't help you unless you tell us [what you did](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2198/33476). Are there any logs on the Pi which show the unsuccessful login attempts?

Comment: I told exactly what I did.Follwed the guide step by step: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md. Nothing else. How can I check the logs on the raspberry?. Also, found simmilar thread regarding simmilar problem: https://forum.openwrt.org/t/raspberry-pi-3b-access-point-unreliable/62619. However, still no clear answer, just some speculations. Tried few suggestions they have suggested but no fix. My mission now is to determine whether its PI or ESP32 issue. I think its PI because connection to my phone is also strange as I mentioned previously

Comment: If you followed the guide precisely, then your AP is as good as it gets, unless someone comes up with a better guide. Sorry.

Comment: These things do not live up to the hype, mine will not boot with a keyboard attached or my Pi 4 does not anyways, with that keyboard, actually would not recognize my wireless usb dongle one too, so two now I think...